# https causing cloudflare error 524 on my servers

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04, cloudflare

I've been hemorrhaging hours of research to this and cannot seem to find the right solution, even to understand the problem itself.

The scenario:
I have an multiple ubuntu servers, each server runs an apache hosting multiple sites via apache-vhost. I have a CloudFlare free plan and configures it to only do **Flexible SSL/TSL** and a **Page Rule** to force HTTPS access.

The problem:
Some client gets Cloudflare 524 Error while some are just fine.

Tests/Observations:

1. If I disabled the **Page Rule** force HTTPS, everything is fine. So this should point on the https problem, but why does the https works on some, and not on the other clients?
2. http requests are properly logged in the access-log of each vhosted site, I tried it myself, it actually logged my request but I still get Error 524.
3. The servers are not overloaded but I still get Error 524.
4. Increased the mpm_prefork settings, still Error 524.
5. Disallowed any IPs except cloudflare ips via iptables, still Error 524
6. Disabled multiple vhosted site, still Error 524

I'm currently out of idea on how to understand this problem to solve it. I've been exhausing weeks of research but all threads mentioning this specific error doesn't fit with my case. Help!

Comment: 524 is an error you get, when cloudflare is able to connect to your server, but the total response time takes to long. e.g. your server needs 30 seconds to generate the response page, and cloudflare timeout is set to 10 seconds.  with tcpdump, and apache mod-dumpio you can verify how log it takes to respond.

Comment: maybe your server has an infinity loop or just really needs to much time to send a response, as 524 means that the request timed out...

Comment: When CloudFlare successfully connects to the web server but does not receive a response before the set timeout period, it terminates the connection with the error: "Error 524: A timeout occurred". From your description it can be concluded that you do not have problems with the servers themselves. Probably the error is in one of the routers on the way or in a specific CloudFlare datacentre. Check how the routing routes differ for failed client connections and for connections where there is no error. You give too little detail which does not allow for analysis and you can only guess the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

you said you enabled force HTTPS with cloudflare.
Do you even have an SSL certificate on your server? Without this, an https connection is not possible.

If that's the case try to run the following commands:

1. `sudo apt-get install certbot python-certbot-apache`
2. `certbot --apache -d example.com`
3. Enter you email address

This should automaticly generate a certificat for your domain.

Note: when you have subdomains, you have to issue a separate certificate for them!

Comment: I don't need SSL certificate on my server since on cloudflare my configuration is not Full, its Flexible. Additionally, if its fully the case, all clients should not be able to access the websites

Comment: apache has mod-md, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ja/mod/mod_md.html no more messing around with certbot, apache can do the let's encrypt stuff by itself.

Answer (score 0):

524 Error means that cloudflare got a timeout from your server.

Try looking at your logs for long running pages that might be exceeding the cloudflare timeout threshold (probably 100 seconds).

What looks like a client problem is really just the nature of random timeouts impacting different clients differently.

http://windowsbulletin.com/how-to-fix-cloudflare-error-524-a-timeout-occurred/

Comment: there are none long running process, the servers are idle

Comment: Long running processes was an example of what could cause a timeout. Cloud flare is getting a timeout from you. Diagnosing why will require some detective work.